# Fix children container width trouble

Tags: react-native

My children views may be a different width, but it not be bigger than parent view. How can I fix it?

This is a screenshot of how it looks now:

[image]

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help (**"why isn't this code working?"**) must include *the desired behavior*, *a specific problem or error* and *the shortest code necessary* to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

you can give your parent view width as device window width like this:

```
var {height, width} = Dimensions.get('window');
```

Implement height and width as you required like this in your parent view:

```
<View style={{height:height, width:width}}></View>
```

After constructing your parent view, you can give your child view width and height as your own interest like :

```
style={{height:40, width:250}}
```

also you should have some knowledge on react-native flex to construct others layout you can view from [here](http://moduscreate.com/react-native-layout-system/)

Answer (score 0):

I would need to see your code, but for React, you should be using Flexbox to align children for consistency.

http://moduscreate.com/aligning-children-using-flexbox-in-react-native/